# Visual Studio Project 2019 project still require msvcr120d.dll

Tags: c++, migration, visual-studio-2019

I migrate Visual Studio 2013 project to visual studio 2019 and recompiler my all dlls and other files using visual studio 2019. But when I run my application, it still requires msvcr120d.dll in release mode.

Anyone help me out to fix this.

Comment: Check the project Platform and Toolset settings

Comment: checked for release/debug there are no dependencies on msvcr120d.dll but have a dependency on msvrt.lib that require for visual studio 2019 only and also platform set to v142

Comment: @SahilGoyal "*it still requires* ***msvcr120d.dll*** *in release mode*" The "***d***" in "*msvcr120d*" stands for "debug". You should not be linking debug runtimes to a release build, and that's the first problem you need to solve. Use [`dumpbin /imports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/imports-dumpbin?view=msvc-160) to see which of your EXEs or DLLs link to `msvcr120d` in the release build.

Comment: @dxiv   thanks for help dumpbin /DEPENDENTS my.exe and dumpbin /DEPENDENTS my.dll resolve my problem and now I am able to find where  msvcr120d dependency coming

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and select proper `Platform Toolset`

for `vs2019` select `v142`

[image]